# Chrome extension to Indicate/show the CA Root certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-devtools, fiddler, root-certificate

I'm using Fiddler2 on Windows to inspect and analyze HTTPS traffic.  To make it less cumbersome, I've installed and trusted the Fiddler2 Root certificate.  The Fiddler root certificate makes the browsing experience seamless; all the HTTPS sites are still "secured" (ie: the url is still https, and you still see a certificate lock).

But this becomes problematic when I forget to turn off Fiddler, and find myself browsing sites that I want to remain secured, only to find Fiddler still logging my traffic/content.

Is there a Chrome extension that I can install/use that would visible show when the HTTPS connection is secured by a certificate signed by a specific root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like such information is available in the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API, which you would need to get it in a Chrome Extension.

There was previously a request to [Provide information about the TLS connections to extensions via the webRequest API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107793), but it was decided not to be implemented.